Is Individual soul created or an eternal being according to Madhva and Ramanuja? if God is all pervading, why we have to go vaikuta after mukti?
Namo vaḥ
As per Madhva and Ramanuja individual souls are separate and not equal to Brahman.
if so, Is individual soul(jivatma) created? If it is created, why God created us separate from him? Just to abandoned his creation by throwing them into samsara and watching them suffer from his abode(Vaikunta/Heavens)? Only liberating the souls that are completely surrendered to him, praises him always, and does so much penance for his satisfaction? Isn't it cruel?
They(Ramanujas or Madhvas) may say that God didn't abandoned us, he always dwell in individual souls.
If god is in every being, then why we have to go to a place outside the world (like vaikunta) after liberation and wait for the promotions their like salokya, srupya, sameepya and saasti?
If individual souls are eternal entities separate from him (not manifested from him), then why God has to force these being into the cycle of samsara.
They(Ramanujas or Madhvas) may say that God is putting these jivatmas into samsara because of their past karma in past kalpa(creation) and these Jagat is in unending cycle of birth and rebirth(creation and destruction).
With this explanation there comes the following assumptions:
if jivatma is a dependent being, then there is a time where it did not commented or performed any action for it to enter in to samsara and it is God that thrown jivatmas into samsara. again, isn't that cruel?
if jivatma is an independent being, then it has nothing to do with God for its liberation, just complete cessation of mind(flow of thoughts) and voluntary actions is enough. Which will lead into argument of God being mere giver of result or even nireswara vaada.
Please give me the clarification on the views of these philosophers(Madhvacharya and Ramanujacharya) regarding soul(individual self/jivatma) being created or not created and dependent or independent
P.S: I believe in advaita interpretation of vedanta by Goudapadacharya and Sankaracharya as ultimate truth because apart from darsanas like sankya and yoga etc, other darsanas like pancharatra, pasupata, vishista advaita, tatvavada etc present god as cruel being with massive ego like abrahamic god that thrown us into this world for fun
